# Click not working on youtube button to play video with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm writing an extension for watching videos on YouTube. A site opens with a timer in which the YouTube iframe is located. I just need to play the video. I do it with a click. The problem is that it doesn't work. Access to the iframe is in the manifest. The click happens, the screen blinks for a second, and nothing happens. It is interesting that sometimes it works without problems. I do not understand what the problem is.

```
manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",  
    "description": "test",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs","storage","<all_urls>","activeTab"],  
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["background.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
    ],
}
```

bacground.js:

```
const delay = millis => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(_ => resolve(), millis)
});
async function test(){
var url = window.location.toString();
var ytframe = "www.youtube.com/embed";
var resultytframe = url.match(ytframe);
   if(resultytframe==ytframe){
      document.querySelectorAll("button[class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")[0].click();
   }
}
test();
```

Also, everything will work if I make a physical mouse click anywhere(besides the play button) or write something to the console before work background.js.
Video for example: https://youtu.be/rlf0eVyPf8w

Comment: Use *event delegation*.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how this can help me. Event delegation can just track the click, and depending on the situation, perform a certain action. But what does it give me?

Comment: Try .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))

Comment: I tried it. The code works. But the situation is the same as in the video. It did not help:(
`document.querySelector("button[class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));`

Comment: Everything works if you insert the code into the console yourself. But when it does chrome extension it doesn't work

Comment: Apparently the button's listener is added by the page after your script runs. Try delaying your code e.g. setTimeout(test, 1000) or use MutationObserver.

Comment: I set it to 10 seconds, it didn't help. Here is an example link to the iframe where I am trying to do this: https://goo.su/xbILNCy. Maybe YouTube has some kind of protection? If you just right-click on the video and the menu window will drop out, then some kind of "activation process" of the window/page will take place, in this case the chrome extension works, until I do this it does not start working:(

Comment: Indeed, it might be the case because user-activation is often required to play unmuted videos. You can try setting `muted` property on the `video` element first.

Comment: aha, it really has to do with sound. Before that, I turned off the sound in the browser settings and at that moment the code stopped working as it should, I could not think that this was the problem. Now I allowed the sound on YouTube and everything started working. Thank you very much for helping me figure out what the problem is =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on the sound for YouTube in the browser settings. This problem arose in my Brave browser on Chromium: 89.0.4389.72, I decided to check it in Google Chrome browser on Chromium 102.0.5005.63, there is no such problem and you can turn off the sound